# How to send json POST request using requests if the website uses jwt?

Tags: python, json, python-requests

i am trying to send POST request to login to this [URL](https://my.te.eg/#/home/signin/UnAuthorized)
, i first checked the network tab and found out the the post request is being sent to this

url : https://api-my.te.eg/api/user/login?channelId=WEB_APP

and the request payload is:

```
{
   "header":{
      "timstamp":0,
      "customerId":null,
      "msisdn":null,
      "messageCode":null,
      "responseCode":"1200",
      "responseMessage":"Your Session has been expired, please sign in to continue",
      "locale":null,
      "referenceId":null,
      "channelId":null,
      "responeAdditionalParameters":null
   },
   "body":null
}
```

Here is the code :

```
import requests
import calendar
import time
#Here i tried to send a generated timestamp, idk if this is needed or not
ts = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
loginUrl = 'https://api-my.te.eg/api/user/login?channelId=WEB_APP'
values = {
    "msisdn": MobileNumberID,
    "timestamp": str(ts),
    "locale": "Ar"
}

data = {
    "password": PasswordID
}

url = requests.post(loginUrl , data=data , headers=values)
print(url.text)
```

Comment: Is that your REAL password or just a dummy?

Comment: does it matter ?  it's encrypted and i added some letters to it

Comment: no username , actually it's a phone number but this isn't important since it's ```msisdn``` in the json

Comment: Take a look at this piece in the documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests At the end of that paragraph they describe the `json` parameter when making requests.

Comment: i know how to use requests, this is not the problem , the problem is that is the website uses ```jwt``` . i ended up using ```selenium```

Comment: it's not possible to send post requests due to the website security as they use jwt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the site and in the body they are also passing a header property in the data

So you should use

```
data = {
  "header": {
    "msisdn": "024568478",
    "timestamp": "1592337873",
    "locale": "Ar"
  },
  "body": {
    "password": "PJGkRJte5ntnKt9TQ8XM3Q=="
  }
}
```

and in headers you should pass the native headers probably something like:

```
headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', }
```

but i also see by when you log into this site they pass a [jwt](https://jwt.io/introduction/) argument in the headers. Looks like its some sort of built in security. So it looks like you can not use this API. Its only for the backend of this site.

Did you search the site to see if they have API documentation, maybe their is written how you can calculate the value for jwt?

EDIT:

When you get the login working this is. How to use sessions in python requests:

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {"login":"my_login", "password":"my_password"}
url = "http://example.net/login"
r = s.post(url, data=data)
```

If you do not get arround the jwt. You can uses [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) in python. It works by automating a webbrowser. So you can open chrome tell it wich page to load, fill in your login form and read the html of elements in the browser. This will work on 95% of the websites. Some even have protections against it. Some sites use cloudflare, they are protected from selenium automation.

Comment: gives me the same log as before, the passed password is ```str``` and not encrypted , also the ```timestamp``` is different from the generated one (which i don't know if it's needed or not)

Comment: i guess you're right, i tried to find an API but no luck , also i tried to decode the ```jwt``` and found out that they user HS256

Comment: i guess i can calculate the jwt using this site : https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/ , they use the same format and they give you 2 min after those 2 mins your session is expired

Comment: I added some other things in my answer, look behind EDIT:

Comment: i tried the session one but didn't work , so i use selenium , thanks

Comment: Good luck with your project!

Comment: i just got banned from stackoverflow for asking too many question, even though i didn't :'(

Comment: thank you @gerrit-geeraerts ,, i used selenium :D